# Use of Matchers.isNull() for generic classes

Tags: java, generics, mockito, java-7

Im using Mockito to test a method like this:

```
myMethod(String s, List<Integer> i);
```

I use this call:

```
doReturn(foo).when(bar).myMethod(anyString(), isNull(List.class))
```

The use of the `isNull(Class<?> class)` method is my problem here. Because I use anyString(), which is a Matcher, I can't just pass `null`.

Now I get a `type safety` warning, because of the use of a generic class. I can get rid of it using the `@SuppressWarning` Annotation.

This problem is more Java related then Mockito but I wanted to provide the use case, where I can't just use an instance of the List to pass it to the method.

What I would like to know in first place is a clean way to get rid of the warning. Because casting (generics, type eraser) is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the generic version of [`Matchers.eq()`](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq(T)):

```
doReturn(foo).when(bar).myMethod(anyString(), Matchers.<List<Integer>> eq(null))
```

Using Java 7 you have to add the type witness `<List<Integer>>` to help the compiler figure this all out. In Java 8, that's not required. For more info on that particular aspect, see the bottom paragraphs of [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

Comment: This doesn't work, because eq(...) returns Object. The compiler won't let me do this without casting.

Comment: @SteveBenett Sorry, I was using Java 8 which compiled this without a problem. I see you are using Java 7.